# Software for renting (a monitor)

Tags: gratis, calendar, reminders, google-calendar, booking

we have a company that displays commericals on outdoor monitors.

I would need a software, where I can see when a monitor is booked by whom:

- There are up to 10 clients on one monitor at once
- I would like to see it in kinda a calender view (Google calendar integration would be dope)
- I need to set multiple reminders for a booking (one for when it starts and one for when it ends)
- These reminders should then pop up in my Google calendar
  There's no need for website integration or anything. Only we work in this tool, no booking by customers.

Is there any such tool out there? Freeware would be great since we are a start up in dire straits.

Comment: Hi & Welcome. Will the platform also be used for payments, etc?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. No, it's just that we know when slots are booked.

Answer (score 1):

The opensource system that I recommend is [LibreBooking](https://github.com/LibreBooking/app) - the free version of BookedScheduler.

- It can handle most kind of resources.
- It is multi-user.
- It has start/end reminders.
- It can show calendar views of bookings.
- I can't recall if you can export calendar. But check the issues queue.

There is a demo of BookedScheduler [here](https://demo.bookedscheduler.com/Web/index.php).

Comment: Great! I will check this out. Thank you very much!